# Bitlocker -> usb read only

Tags: usb, encryption, bitlocker, copy, protected

I have Bitlocker installed and want to copy a file to a usb stick. Bitlocker denies that and consider the usb drive as write protected. I do not want to encrypt the stick. Is there any way to bypass this problem so I can copy a file?

Comment: The drive may have simply failed or is about to and switched itself to read-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Removable Data Drives*
- Ensure that
  "Deny write access to removable drives not protected by BitLocker"
  is set to "Not Configured" or "Disabled".

For more information (and registry update method) see the article
[Allow or Deny Write Access to Removable Drives not Protected by BitLocker in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96998-deny-write-access-removable-drives-not-protected-bitlocker.html).

Comment: Thanks Harrymc - but I have tried that already. Both with "not config" and later "disabled" for removable disk. + reboot in between. No change - problem still exist.

Comment: Are all the policies in that branch marked as Not configured?

Comment: yes - all not configured

Comment: Weird. Try to run `diskpart`, enter `list disk` to locate your device number N, enter `select disk N` and then `attributes disk clear readonly`.

Comment: Thanks Harrymc - have tried your recipe and although I get the feedback that disk attributes cleared succesfully, Bitlocker still consider the disk as write protected and want to encrypt.